# Import urls from an xml file, cache the images

Tags: php, mysql, caching

1. I have a wordpress blog (this does not really matter i think).
2. I have an xml file
3. Doing a cron job every 5 minutes, I import the xml data inside a table
4. On my wordpress blog I pull data from that table and display it

**5. Problem is that i have about 20 images to display from 20 urls - this is slowing my site down**

**6. Is there a way to somehow cache the images and automatically refresh them every 5 minutes when the cron job acts?**

Comment: I take it you are not storing the images locally. You should do so. Then if you have the file in the xml on your local server simply load it from there, if not download it from url. You can even check for images you have that the xml doesn't (put images in directory into an array, and images in xml into an array -- prob already doing this? -- then use in_array(); to do so.

Comment: Hey there, from the xml i get a link to a certain image. How can i store it? can you please give me a few php hints, i'm a newb :(

Comment: You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do the actual saving of the files to the local system. For each file in the XML data, check if the file exists on the local system. If it does not, download it with cURL. Use the local path in the database insert (it may be worth storing the remote URL as well).

Comment: This needs more info and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would really need to see the structure of the xml, if you dont have curl you could use the more simpler file_get_contents(); / file_put_contents();

```
<?php 
//in your loop after you found or matched location and filename.
$img = file_get_contents('http://bla.com/imageLocation.jpg');
$newImageName='would_need_to_see_xml.jpg';
$newImagePath='./image_folder/';
file_put_contents($newImagePath.$newImageName,$img);
?>
```